# How to check if a string have multiple characters Next to each other with PHP?

Tags: php

I want to check string have `|++|` or not:

```
                 if(preg_match("/|++|/", $res)) {
                    echo str_replace("|++|", "\n", $res);
                 } else {
                    echo $res;
                 }
```

but with `preg_match` it is not working. how should I check it?

Comment: `+` are special characters in regex. Try escaping them... `if(preg_match("/|\+\+|/", $res)) {`...

Comment: Why not [`strpos()`](https://php.net/strpos) ?

Comment: `str_replace()` would accomplish the same thing by itself (no need to probe first).

Answer (score 2):

You should enscape + and | `\|\+\+\|`, but better to use `str_contains`.

```php
var_dump(str_contains($res, '|++|'));
```

But in this case, you do not need the condition `str_replace` is sufficient. If the string not contains |++| then nothing will happen.

```php
echo str_replace("|++|", "\n", $res);
```

Answer (score 0):

The | and + characters are special characters in a regex and need to be escaped.

Changing `|++|` to `\|\+\+\|` should do the trick.

Comment: There's also [preg_quote](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php) that can be used.